# How do I make a specific page section visible based on the querystring

Tags: php, get

I want to have a page with 3 sections:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo "Work";
    $_GET['id'] = 'edit';
?>
<a href="protected.php?if=edit">Edit post</a>
<?php
}
else {
    echo "notWork";
}
if (isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 'edit') {
    echo "Editing  . . .";
}?>
```

But I have no idea how to do that page "Edit", will be visible only when we go link `protected.php?if=edit`.

Comment: is id comes from another page.

Comment: @Tomas Can you be still more clear in your question?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar see now if I go to page protected.php i wil see text "Editing  . . .", but I want that text wil be visible only when I go to link  `protected.php?if=edit`

Comment: @TomasLietuva Change `(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == 'edit')` to `(isset($_GET['if']) && $_GET['if'] == 'edit')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok.simply check your page referer with this code :

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

more documentation here 
http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `$_GET['if']` instead of `$_GET['id']` as the url parameter is named `if`.

Answer (score 1):

So, if I go to page `protected.php` and the parameter `if` is `edit`, please change the code. There's a typo!

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['if']) && $_GET['if'] == 'edit') {
        echo "Editing  . . .";
    }
?>
```

Comment: `if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
    echo "Work";
    $_GET['id'] = 'edit';
?>
<a href="protected.php?if=edit">Edit post</a>
<?php
}` this code change too ?

Answer (score 1):

You could include the edit-page according to the id you passed through the URL.
Something like: `if($_GET['id'] == edit) include('edit.php')`

However, doing so without further checks, everybody could see the page just by guessing the right value for `id`. Because of this you'd rather do a check against the user rights every time you include something.

Answer (score 1):

If you want read passed value from url, you can use $_GET['if'] or $_REQUEST['if'] to get that value.

Also as you said "page with 3 sections", so i think you want to be show only on section at time then you should use elseif => http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: I not know why you write $_GET['if'], use $_GET['id'], what is this $_GET['if'] i don't know and can't find in google ;(

Comment: You have mentioned link - protected.php?if=edit , here you passing "if" through get. That' why i have used $_GET['if'] to get value passed variable.